# memtest -- only movement is blinking red + sign in upper left

Tags: memtest

Running memtest from the grub menu. The display looks okay except there is nothing moving as I expect to see. The only action is the red plus sign in the upper left.

There was a beep as the test started but no other indicator.

I'm looking into this because of

```
kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
```

Which others have reported as a bug but which has not been listed as a bug as far as I can tell.

In at least one report this turned out to be a bad memory card. Could be. This is a 10-year old PC that has three memory upgrades using three different RAM vendors. The types are all the same but this could easily be a bad old card.

Comment: Which version of memtest are you running? From which Ubuntu version? In my experience some non-faulty machines are not compatible with modern memtest, but memtest from 16.04 or 14.04 works as expected here.

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @N0rbert It's a 10-year old PC running 20.04. Whatever memtest is released with the current update. I'll try one of the older versions. The BIOS self test passes the memory series but fails an old data drive.

Comment: @heynnema As far as I can tell from the documentation, the memtest offered here does not work with old BIOS systems. Only with UEFI. Am I misreading the docs?

Comment: Many  computers let you boot into BIOS and test RAM.

Comment: True. But I believe that they do have an older version available on the web site too.